# Problemas com o interpretador do vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, importação, virtualenv, interpretador

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bem, o Código funciona, eu mudei o interpretador do vscode que estava no python 3.7 global do ubuntu mesmo para o python da virtualenv, o código funciona, mas não entendo o porque desse erro em Problems. Estou importando certo, e o código roda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como visto na segunda imagem, colocando ponto depois do from e antes do dir, o erro desaparece, porém o código ao ser rodado apresenta esse erro:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 1, in 
    from .Twitter.searchTweets import Twitter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.Twitter'; '**main**' is not a package

Infelizmente não estou conseguindo entender esse tipo de problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando um import é feito utilizando '.nome ' é um import relativo, que só funciona caso o "módulo pai"(parent module) é importado junto.

Exemplo:

```
`from Twitter.searchTweets`
```

Você está importando o searchTweets que é relativo ao Twitter, então colocar o ponto antes do Twitter (.Twitter.searchTweets) você está dizendo que o Twitter é relativo a outro módulo pai.

Logo, a primeira imagem apresenta a sintaxe certa, porém apresenta um erro de import que é causado justamente pelo intepretador como você disse, quando uso o VSCode no ubuntu costumo rodar o código em um terminal separado onde posso configurar os ambientes mais facilmente, evitando erros com as IDE's, provavelmente não é a prática mais saudável, mas é uma solução.